# React map return ID of an object like undefined when it has ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

**I'm mapping data to make a table with it, but I get all the properties of the object fine minus the object id.
But when I print the whole array of objects it is right there.
I don't know what is happening here.**

HERE IS THE OUPUT IN THE CONSOLE: http://prntscr.com/pmjk0t

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

interface FetchLibroDataState {

    libroList: LibroData[];

    loading: boolean;

}

export class FetchLibro extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, FetchLibroDataState> {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = { libroList: [], loading: true };

        fetch('api/Libro/Index')

            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<LibroData[]>)

            .then(data => {

                this.setState({ libroList: data, loading: false });

                console.log(data);

            });

        // This binding is necessary to make "this" work in the callback  

        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);

        this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);

    }

    public render() {

        let contents = this.state.loading

            ? <p><em>Cargando...</em></p>

            : this.renderLibroTable(this.state.libroList);

        return <div>

            <h1>Libro Datos</h1>

            <p>Traer datos de la base de datos de Libros.</p>

            <p>

                <Link to="/addlibro">Crear Nuevo</Link>

            </p>

            {contents}

        </div>;

    }

    // Handle Delete request for an employee  

    private handleDelete(id: number) {

        if (!window.confirm("¿Quieres eliminar el libro con el ID: " + id + " ?"))

            return;

        else {

            fetch('api/Libro/Delete/' + id, {

                method: 'delete'

            }).then(data => {

                this.setState(

                    {

                        libroList: this.state.libroList.filter((rec) => {

                            return (rec.IdLibro != id);

                        })

                    });

            });

        }

    }

    private handleEdit(id: number) {

        this.props.history.push("/Libro/edit/" + id);

    }

    // Returns the HTML table to the render() method.  

    private renderLibroTable(libroList: LibroData[]) {

        return <table className='table'>

            <thead>

                <tr>

                    <th></th>

                    <th>Libro ID</th>

                    <th>Autor</th>

                    <th>Nombre</th>

                    <th>Editorial</th>

                    <th>Edicion</th>

                    <th>Genero</th>

                    <th>Año</th>

                    <th>Disponibilidad</th>

                    <th>Cantidad</th>

                    <th>Imagen</th>

                    <th>Sinopsis</th>

                </tr>

            </thead>

            <tbody>

                {libroList.map(libro =>

                    <tr key={libro.IdLibro}>

                        <td></td>

                        <td>{libro.IdLibro}A</td>

                        <td>{libro.nombreAutor}</td>

                        <td>{libro.nombre}</td>

                        <td>{libro.editorial}</td>

                        <td>{libro.edicion}</td>

                        <td>{libro.genero}</td>

                        <td>{libro.ano}</td>

                        <td>{libro.disponibilidad}</td>

                        <td>{libro.cantidad}</td>

                        <td>{libro.imagen}</td>

                        <td>{libro.sinopsis}</td>

                        <td>

                            <a className="action" onClick={(id) => this.handleEdit(libro.IdLibro)}>Edit</a>  |

                            <a className="action" onClick={(id) => this.handleDelete(libro.IdLibro)}>Delete</a>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                )}

            </tbody>

        </table>;

    }

}

export class LibroData {

    IdLibro: number = 0;

    nombreAutor: string = "";

    nombre: string = "";

    editorial: string = "";

    edicion: string = "";

    genero: string = "";

    ano: string = "";

    disponibilidad: boolean = true;

    cantidad: number = 0;

    imagen: string = "";

    sinopsis: string = "";

}
```

Comment: you are mapping for `IdLibro` while the data property is `idLibro`

Comment: Yes! It works, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the property name you are using is not correct, do it as this

```
...
{libroList.map(libro =>

            <tr key={libro.idLibro}> // i is small caps

                <td></td>

                <td>{libro.idLibro}A</td>
             // remaining code
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @JakeChavez if it helped you, please feel free to accept the answer, cheers